# Add a pause bewteen a for-in loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-in-loop

I have a script that accesses a website over 100 times and want to add a small delay between each item. Also, if possible, maybe add a countdown or process bar displaying the status or number of items left. The code example is below;

```
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/440/vehicletype/car?format=csv', 
    'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/441/vehicletype/car?format=csv', 
    'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/442/vehicletype/car?format=csv', 
    'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/443/vehicletype/car?format=csv', 
    'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/445/vehicletype/car?format=csv', 
    'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeIdYear/makeId/448/vehicletype/car?format=csv']             


dfs = [pd.read_csv(url) for url in urls]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)                                                                                      
df.to_csv('foo.csv')
```

Comment: Read about `tqdm` for a countdown bar and `time.sleep` for suspending the execution.

Comment: Curious - why do you want to add a pause?

Comment: @Parfait because running the script accesses the same server so quick after so many server requests, the server blocks it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time 
dfs = []
num = len(urls)
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
  dfs.append(pd.read_csv(url))
  print 'Process {}, {} left'.format(i+1, num-i-1)
  time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly!

Comment: @KyleRichards :)